# How to create a HTML button to add a new item to the page?

Tags: html, button

I want to create a button in HTML that allows the user to create a new item on the page... Basically when the button will be pressed it will ask "Name of the button" and "URL for that button" and when its created the new named item will appear as a button on the same page....

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Ali Can you please share your code?

Comment: If you want to keep the button you'd need to store the button in a database, also to code this you'll need javascript